# Problem with reading value of TextEdit Box

Tags: c++, c, winapi, desktop

Im trying to read the value of a `TextEdit` box in a windows dialog and display the results using a `MessageBox`, however the results being displayed is just “Error”, when I run the program, even though there are no exceptions or error message in the debug section in visual studio. What am i doing wrong? Here is the subject code:

```
LPWSTR path;
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_PROGRAM, path, sizeof(path));
MessageBox(hDlg, NULL, path, MB_OK);
```

Comment: `sizeof(path)` is the size of a pointer. Your path variable is an uninitialized pointer to a wide string

Comment: The last parameter must be the maximum size of the path, not the size of the pointer.

Comment: It works fine now! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an uninitialized pointer and an incorrect buffer size to `GetDlgItemText()`.

You need to allocate memory for a buffer for `GetDlgItemText()` to write into, and specify the max size of that buffer, eg:

```cpp
WHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_PROGRAM, path, MAX_PATH);
MessageBox(hDlg, NULL, path, MB_OK);
```